# Unable to Load Data in Amazon Neptune from S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-neptune

I am using Amazon Neptune as GraphDB.

While trying to load data from the S3 bucket facing an exception mentioning 
**"{"code":"InvalidParameterException","detailedMessage":"The source *s3-URL* does not exist/not reachable"}".**

Have checked the S3 resource URL, it is accessible publicly.
Unable to understand why this error is coming.

I have referred [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-data.html) AWS documentation and use the below post call to the Neptune DB instance for the data loading.

> ```
> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' neptune-endpoint:8182/loader -d '
> {
>       "source" : "s3-URL",
>       "format" : "csv",
>       "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::",
>       "region" : "us-east-2",
>       "failOnError" : "FALSE",
>       "parallelism" : "MEDIUM",
>       "updateSingleCardinalityProperties" : "FALSE"
> }'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error message, it appears like you forgot to replace the placeholder `s3-URL`. You basically need to put your data in S3, and use a S3 URL to the folder to make a bulk load request.

Also, your snippet does not have a valid value for `iamRoleArn` either. Please go through the docs in detail, as it explains a bunch of steps that need to be done to make a successful S3 Load. The short summary of steps are as follows:

1. Upload your CSV or RDF data into S3, obtain the S3 URL
2. Create an IAM Role who has access to the S3 data
3. Use the `addRoleToDbCluster` API (or console) to add this role to the cluster. This makes the cluster impersonate that role when needed to fetch data.
4. Attach a VPC-Endpoint to your VPC, so that it can talk to S3.
5. Fire the `/loader` request and track status of your load.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the VPC endpoint?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load.html

Comment: Also, the URl has to be one of these: 
s3://bucket_name/object-key-name
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/object-key-name
https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/object-key-name

Answer (score 0):

**Create gateway endpoint instated interface endpoint**

[Check Simple Description Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/security-vpc.html)